# How can I make paginate this simple line of PHP code?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to know how can I paginate this very simple of line of code:

```
    <?php

for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++){
    echo '<a href="#">'.$i.'</a> | ';
}

?>
```

it's ouput:

[image]

I want to make it like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the page links to "surround" the current page. I haven't included previous and next links, which are trivial to add and would confuse this example.

```
<?php

$current_page = 10;
$total_pages = 40;
$links = 11;

$start = $current_page - floor($links / 2);
if ($start < 1) {
    $start = 1;
}

$end = $start + $links;
if ($end > $total_pages) {
    $end = $total_pages;
}

for($i = $start; $i <= $end; ++$i) {
    echo '<a href="#">' . $i . '</a> | ';
}

?>
```

For page 20, it would give you the current page and 5 pages either side:

```
15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will solve your problem:

```
if($_GET['page']!=''){
    $page=$_GET['page'];
} else {
    $page=1;
}

print "<a href=\"?page=".($page==1 ? '1' : $page-1)."\">Prev</a> |\n";

for($i=$page;$i<=($page+10);$i++){
    print "<a href=\"?page={$i}\">{$i}</a> |\n";
}

print "<a href=\"?page=".($page+1)."\">Next</a>\n";
```

You'll obviously need to tweak for whatever your purpose is.